# What are the names of the computers, that were used in the CP/M advertisement?

Tags: identify-this-computer, cp-m

I am reading the article about the [CP/M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP/M) operating system and wonder which computers are displayed in this picture. I have recognized the "IBM PC" only - in the middle.

[image: CP/M GRAPHICS ad with three computers pictured.]

Comment: The advert can be seen in its original setting on [the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Infoworld-1982-11-29#page/n93/mode/2up).

Comment: Good question! It got me rummaging around, trying to identify the plotter. :-)

Comment: @StephenKitt Unfortunately link is broken now :-/

Comment: Ah yes, thanks @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, PC Magazine, InfoWorld etc. have been taken down from the IA; they’re on Google Books, [here’s the ad there](https://books.google.fr/books?id=HjAEAAAAMBAJ&lpg=PA93&pg=PA93#v=onepage&f=false).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From left to right:

- [DEC VT100](http://www.columbia.edu/cu/computinghistory/vt100.html) family terminal, which may have been connected to some other system or in [VT180](http://www.old-computers.com/museum/computer.asp?st=1&c=605) form, which was a VT100 with a card that turned it into a standalone computer.
- [IBM PC 5150](http://www.old-computers.com/museum/computer.asp?st=1&c=274)
- [NEC APC](http://www.old-computers.com/museum/computer.asp?st=1&c=333)

Comment: It is most likely a [VT180](http://www.vintage-computer.com/decrobin.shtml) - nearly identical to a VT100 form factor with floppy drives in an separate case.  I used to have one.  A rather ordinary machine for its time, not at all speedy in any way, but I did a lot of work on DEC equipment back then so I was quite comfortable with it. I have to say, I don't remember it having a color display … but it's possible I suppose … or it could be advertiser's license, as suggested by Stephen Kitt in a comment on Alex Hajnal's answer.

Comment: Interesting that DRI was spending money on full-page ads in 1983 to get people to run CP/M on the IBM PC. With hindsight that seems quixotic. I guess they were desperate and their next-generation successor to CP/M was not yet ready for market.

Comment: @BenCrowell By the time that ad would have been prepped for publication (late summer, 1982), CP/M-80 was still very much a thing, the PC had been on the market for about a year and enough other systems were adopting the 8086 that it looked like CP/M-86 could have taken off.

Answer (score 7):

Left-to-right it looks like a [DEC VT125](http://terminals-wiki.org/wiki/index.php/DEC_VT125) <sup>1</sup>, [IBM 5150](http://oldcomputers.net/ibm5150.html), and [NEC APC](http://oldcomputers.net/nec-apc.html).  One of the objects in the background appears to be an [HP 7470A](http://www.hpmuseum.net/display_item.php?hw=73) plotter (thanks to Mick for pointing that out).

<sup>1</sup> The VT125 had color bitmap capability.

Comment: The "printer" in the background looks like a pen plotter (and the guy is holding the output). Probably an [HP 7470A](http://www.hpmuseum.net/display_item.php?hw=73).

Comment: I think you're right on that.  Had a hunch it would be given that the ad's selling a graphics library.

Comment: Back then it was common for images on screens in pictures to be added to the photo after the fact, because it was very hard to get a pleasing result by photographing on-screen images; so it’s quite possible that the colour chart doesn’t reflect the actual capabilities of the devices portrayed. The DEC device could be a VT125, or a VT180, or...

Comment: The screen on the right looks like a cut-and-paste of the screen on the left!

Comment: definitely a 7470A: simple two-pen A4/Letter gritwheel plotter. I have one. It's pretty neat, in a very simplistic way.

Answer (score 5):

The right one looks like a NEC APC or N5200.

The middle, as you rightly say, is an IBM PC.

The left one, isn't even a computer - looks like a DEC VT100 terminal to me.

So, the computers in the picture would only run CP/M 86. No "classic" CP/M 80, unfortunately, and no CP/M 68k.